# Oracle SQL - joining tables based on value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:

```
ITEM_LOCATION
ITEM   LOC
100    K1
200    J1
300    A1

ITEM_TRAITS
ITEM   LOC  ORDER_IND
100    K1     N
100    J1     Y
```

I need the result:

```
ITEM   LOC
200    J1
300    A1
```

excluding all items / loc from ITEM_TRAITS having ORDER_IND = N

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select il.*
from item_location il
where not exists (select 1
                  from item_traits it
                  where it.item = il.item and 
                        it.loc = il.loc and
                        it.order_ind = 'N'
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ITEM, LOC
FROM ITEM_LOCATION
EXCEPT
SELECT ITEM, LOC
FROM ITEM_TRAITS
WHERE ORDER_IND <> 'N'
```

I thnik it's the simplest variant.
But if i got your message right **"excluding all items / loc from ITEM_TRAITS having ORDER_IND = N"**

If i ignore it and just watch on the data the WHERE clause should be:
WHERE ORDER_IND = 'N'